# highcharts how to load data via ajax

Tags: ajax, highcharts

I hvae an application where highchart is getting data via ajax. But for some reason highchart is not loading. 
I looked at a demo given on highcharts website for loading highcharts via ajax. That doesnt seem to work either. 
Here is the url 
[highcharts ajax demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/edge/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-ajax/)

Can you please let me know what is wring here?

Answer (score 1):

Two changes worked for me.

1. Change the reference for the analytics.tsv file to look for a csv file in the local directory.

   `$.get('analytics.csv', function(csv) {`
2. Convert the tsv (tab separated values) to a comma separated values (csv) file

   `cat analytics.tsv | sed -e 's/\t/,/g' > analytics.csv`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be if you are trying to fetch the .tsv file from Highcharts.com servers or if you have not given the correct relative path to analytics.tsv. I have personally tried the sample that you can download from [here](http://www.highcharts.com/download) and their ajax sample seems to work just fine.

I think you should check out the discussion [here](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=15385).

The discussion is about fetching a json file via jQuery AJAX calls and populating a chart's series with the data. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Please familair with related article http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing, morever you can experienced cross domain issue witk loading files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to run a line chart with ajax loaded data. In my case there was a missing line in the main file (where the container was) which was:

```
<script src="scripts/modules/data.js."></script>
```

I just didn't include it to the page, and that caused the whole problem.